# JDBC Connection close conecpt

Tags: java, jdbc

I have created connection's object and stored in the hashMap. While executing query on the connection object I retrieve the object from the hashMap. In finally block I close the connection. 
However, when we come for the second time I again retrieve the connection's object from the hashMap. This time while executing the query I get closed connection exception.
If I remove conn.close() from finally, it works.
what is the reason behind this? Moreover, when i print the connection's object I get the object.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You closed the connection, and are now surprised that it is closed?!

Comment: I have closed the connection. But before that I have stored it in the hashMap.

Comment: You **closed** the connection. That doesn't mean that the connection object is gone, it just means it is no longer connected to the database, and thus can no longer be used.

Comment: Thank You Mark..

Comment: But can't we do anything to utilize the stored connection object. Like making it to again get connected to the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are re-using the same `Connection` object for multiple queries, you shouldn't close the connection after each time you use it, since closing it means the second query will fail.

Therefore, you should either create a new open `Connection` for each query, or keep the cached `Connection` open (i.e. don't close it in the `finally` block).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go for a connection  pool implementation instead of a simple Map of connections. Here when you close a connection after each transaction, the life cycle of the connection ends, and you can not reuse it from the map.

Think of a connection pool which can get you an already opened connection, and return/release the connection back to the pool once your usage is done.

Comment: But when you go on printing the connection's object it gives you the object. why it is so???

Comment: Still the Connection will be there in your map, but it is a closed connection, that can not be reused. Unless you remove the connection entry from the map it will be available in the map.

Comment: Okey Thank you.. What else can be done to reutilize it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move to some implementation of the connection pool.

P.S. It would be helpful to see your code

Comment: better be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close Connection after each sql statement. 
Newly created Connection is in auto-commit mode :
By default, new connections are in auto-commit mode. From `Connection.setAutoCommit` doc:

> The commit occurs when the statement completes. The time when the
>   statement completes depends on the type of SQL Statement:  •For DML
>   statements, such as Insert, Update or Delete, and DDL statements, the
>   statement is complete as soon as it has finished executing.  •For
>   Select statements, the statement is complete when the associated
>   result set is closed.  •For CallableStatement objects or for
>   statements that return multiple results, the statement is complete
>   when all of the associated result sets have been closed, and all
>   update counts and output parameters have been retrieved.

But if you set auto-commit to false you have to call `Connection.commit` method to update database.